# Uneven column height when using CSS column-count

Tags: html, css

I've got a [page full of cards](http://bchi-staging.herokuapp.com/cities/74/snapshots) that I'd like to divide into two columns. So far so good, but in Firefox/Win, the heights of the two columns are way different — there's a big gap at the bottom of the first column while the other goes on and on...

Here's the relevant CSS for the enclosing div:

```
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 0.8em;                                                             
 column-fill: balance;
```

I'd be very grateful of any help sorting this out.

Comment: Please include full code (HTML and CSS) to allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035224/css-columns-will-not-horizontally-align

Comment: or. . .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314726/css-multi-column-layout-of-list-items-doesnt-align-properly-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code:

```
column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 -moz-column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 0.8em; 
 -webkit-column-gap: 0.8em; 
 -moz-column-gap: 0.8em;
```